# why typescript‘s never conditional-types different in generic and normal type

Tags: typescript

```
type a<T> = T extends {} ? true : false;

type a111 = a<never>; // never

type a222 = never extends {} ? true : false; // true
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QDeAvlAPxTABOArtAFxQBmMANsRANwAoAaEiwAjBLSw4+CADcI9JHygB6VVFkL6QkdBgAmI1K2KsuAiXJVaDZlDace-NRrsQBQA)

I think `a111` and `a222` should be equal, but they are not.
Why the result of a111 and a222 are different?